# Doctrine Mysql: multiple joins in query builder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entities: `Tag`, `User` and `Service`. `Tag` has many-to-many relationship with both `User` and `Service`.

```
 class Service{
      /**
       * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="serviceList")
       */
       private $tagList;
 }

 class User{
       /**
        * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="userList")
        */
       private $tagList;
 }

 class Tag{
       /**
        * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="tagList")
        * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tags_users")
        */
       private $userList;

       /**
        * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="tagList")
        * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tags_services")
        */
       private $serviceList;
 }
```

With query builder how can I return all services that has at least 1 common tag with given `User`, i.e services related to the user

This is a query I have written, but it's doesn't work

```
  $query = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Service')
        ->createQueryBuilder('service')
        ->join('service.tagList', 'serviceTag')
        ->join('AppBundle:BasicUser', 'user')
        ->join('user.tagList', 'userTag')
        ->where('user.id = :id')
        ->andWhere('serviceTag.id = userTag.id')
        ->setParameter('id', $user->getId())
    ;
```

Error:

```
 [Syntax Error] line 0, col 104: Error: Expected Literal, got "JOIN" (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is wrong. I think the easiest solution would be:

```
 $query = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Service')
             ->createQueryBuilder('service')
             ->innerJoin('service.tagList', 'tag')
             ->andWhere(':user MEMBER OF tag.userList')
             ->setParameter('user',$user)
             ;
```